# How can I add a featured image to a page?

Tags: plugins

I need the ability to add an image to a page, like a featured image. How can I do that, and how do I get the featured image to display in page.php? It can be a plugin if what I am asking can't be done within Wordpress itself out of the box.

Comment: custom fields? http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eek! A 33% acceptance rate isn't really going to do you any favours but lucky for you Wordpress' in-built post-thumbnail featured image functionality works for posts, custom post types and pages too.

Add the following line into your theme functions.php file:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'page' ) );
```

Then in your page.php file and I stress that **this must be used within the page loop** (not outside of it) the following function will show your featured image on a page if it has one assigned to it.

```
the_post_thumbnail()
```

Adding a featured image to a page is the same process as adding one to a post. On the page editing screen you will see a metabox with a link that says, '*Set a featured image*' click that and you're good to go. No plugins required.

Comment: All you need to add is `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` and this will also work for pages

Comment: Remember to toggle "featured image" in screen options afterwards.

Comment: How should the exact code look like within the page.php file?